# The 10k-tools reopen votes "sort by close votes" should be "sort by reopen votes"

Tags: bug, 10k-tools

I recently hit 10k and got to look at the 10k tools. While fiddling around with it, I discovered that after clicking "sort by close reason" on the Reopen Votes section, the link to go back has the wrong text:

[image]

The questions linked under this section are already closed, and clicking on that sorts the questions by *reopen* votes. This should read "sort by reopen votes"

Comment: 10k-tools actually need some _love_ and gentle touch in general... It's been asked for a long time :-(